# How to list available ports with boost ASIO?

Tags: boost-asio

I'm trying to use Boost.ASIO Library, And I could not find how to list available ports(with serial port service) or sockets (with the network service) of boost.
Do you know if this is possible ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boost.Asio does not provide this functionality.  Generally, this information is platform dependent.  For example, on Windows, one might use Winsock LSP/SPI for sockets and `SerialPort.GetPortNames` for serial ports.  While on Linux, `/proc/net/*` directories list sockets and serial ports will be enumerated within `/sys/class/tty` .